Airflow XCom_push send variables inside bash command
I'm attempting to send the contents of a variable to Xcom within a bash script in my task, but I'm encountering difficulties. Here's the relevant portion of my code:
task_a = BashOperator(
    task_id="task_a",
    bash_command=""" export hostname=$(hostname -i | awk '{print $1}') \
    && echo "{{ ti.xcom_push(key='k1', value=hostname) }}" \
    && sleep 100 \
    && echo "Command after task a XCom" 
    """,
    dag=dag,
)

However, I'm encountering the following error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'hostname' is undefined. Iwant the bash script sends the Xcom to other tasks and then proceeds with additional works in parallel. How can I resolve this issue?"
